# SQL Database column is a DateTime but I want to search by just time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Column format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'. But I want to search for all rows where that time is between 19:00:00 and 24:00:00

Comment: Is the column a date/time column or a string?  If a string, why are you storing a date/time as a string?

Comment: It's a datetime column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datepart()`:

```
where datepart(hour, col) between 19 and 23
```